# Promote PowerPoint "fields" to SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powerpoint

I know that this is possible with Word and Infopath, but my scenario is that I have PowerPoint slides with some values in some text boxes, which I want to have them (values on text box) promoted into SharePoint Columns on a SharePoint library.

Is this something possible to do? If so, how do I do?

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to promote values from text box in slide into SharePoint columns.

SharePoint has Document Property Promotion and Demotion feature. Property promotion refers to the process of extracting values from properties of a document and writing those values to corresponding columns on the list or document library where the document is stored. Property demotion is the same process in reverse. Values are read from list columns and written to document properties.

Information about [Document Property Promotion and Demotion](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wbaer/2014/08/29/document-property-promotion-and-demotion-overview-and-considerations/).

Use the [document properties of the PowerPoint file](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/View-or-change-the-properties-for-an-Office-file-21D604C2-481E-4379-8E54-1DD4622C6B75) instead of using text box in slide.

Comment: This is more or less I want, the second link is saying "You can assign a text, time, or numeric value to custom properties". Althought it doesn't show how, it says is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually found the solution in the following link.

https://support.winshuttle.com/s/article/Promoting-Fields-in-an-Excel-file-to-SharePoint-List

The link tips does for an excel sheet but tried the same way with the boxes on the PowerPoint slides and it worked. Although I felt not confident with the solution because sometimes the "promotion" did not work and other times did. 
What I did (plus the tips on the link):

- Create Site Columns for each field
- Create a PowerPoint Template with exactly same name of the site columns
- Create a Content Type with the PowerPoint Template
- Associated the Content Type to the library that I want to use
- Create new document based on the document type adjusting the boxes marked as custom properties

These steps gave me the expected behavior: the value in the boxes were "promoted" to the respective SharePoint Columns.